# Tab bar doesn't show system image. xcode. swift 4

Tags: xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar controller. I can change the image of the tab bar icon using the storyboard, and I can select a custom image and it works. However, I see in the list of images many system images, and I would like to use them, but they don't appear when I run the app. I see them in the storyboard fine, but when I run the app I just see the title of the tab bar text, but not the image.

Thanks